# Vue warn Cannot read property of null

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm new to vue and I've been trying to solve this warn in my console about Cannot read property of null. I tried to put a default value in my props but no luck. I can get the value inside `:condition` but inside the console it shows warning can't read property of null

```
props: ['user']
```

Inside heading component:

```
<header-tooltip :total="total" title="High Paying Cash Surveys" :user="user" :condition="user.hpcs" :currency="currency" placeholder="0"></header-tooltip>
```

Warn:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "user.hpcs": TypeError: Cannot read property 'hpcs' of null (found in component: <heading>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got an answer from reading the [vue.js silent](http://v1.vuejs.org/api/#silent) api docs.
These guy will erase all the vue logs and warnings if we wanted our app in production state. Other method is if we install vue via `npm` then we should include the minified vue script inside our blade. Using minified will prevent warnings and logs inside your vue and it's good for production purposes.

Locate your vue js and enter the code below:

```
Vue.config.silent = true
```